# how to add data in 2 table in only one form

Tags: php, registration

HTML CODE

```
<form method = "POST" action = "register.php">
    <div class = "register">
    <center>
        <div class = "heading"></br>
            <strong>--- REGISTER ---</strong></br></br>
        </div>
    </center>

    <div class = "registration">

        First Name: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter First Name" name = "Cus_fname" style = "margin-left: 48px;" required></br></br>
        Last Name: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Last Name" name = "Cus_lname" style = "margin-left: 49px;" required></br></br>
        Username: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Username" name = "Cus_Uname" style = "margin-left: 55px;" required></br></br>
        Password: <input type = "password" placeholder = "Enter Password" name = "Cus_Pword" style = "margin-left: 61px;" required></br></br>
        Address: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Address" name = "Cus_address" style = "margin-left: 67px;" required></br></br>
        Contact No.: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Contact Number" name = "Cus_contactnum" style = "margin-left: 38px;" required></br></br>
        Email: <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter E-mail Address" name = "Cus_email" style = "margin-left: 88px;" required></br></br>

        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" style = "margin-left: 110px;"></br>

    </div></br>
    </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



    $cf = $_POST['Cus_fname'];
    $cl = $_POST['Cus_lname'];
    $cu = $_POST['Cus_Uname'];
    $cp = $_POST['Cus_Pword'];
    $ca = $_POST['Cus_address'];
    $cn = $_POST['Cus_contactnum'];
    $ce = $_POST['Cus_email'];

    include("config.php");


    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO account (Cus_ID, Cus_Uname, Cus_Pword) VALUES ('null', '$cu', '$cp')");
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO client (Cus_ID, Cus_lname, Cus_fname, Cus_address, Cus_contactnum, Cus_email) VALUES(null, '$cl', '$cf', '$ca', '$cn', '$ce')");

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

The problem is that it's only adding on one table which is my client table and it only add 1 data to my account table no more than that

Im Using MySQL Workbench for my database

Comment: Firstly, your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, consider using escape strings or prepare statements. Also, you don't have any checks or defaults for your entries. What if a user didn't enter something or the data did not get posted to the right Index?

Answer (score 2):

Using a prepared statement allows you to protect from SQL Injection. Checking all your posts helps ensure that they have some value if needed.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Populate each variable
    $cf = isset($_POST['Cus_fname'])?$_POST['Cus_fname']:"";
    $cl = isset($_POST['Cus_lname'])?$_POST['Cus_lname']:"";
    $cu = isset($_POST['Cus_Uname'])?$_POST['Cus_Uname']:"";
    $cp = isset($_POST['Cus_Pword'])?$_POST['Cus_Pword']:"";
    $ca = isset($_POST['Cus_address'])?$_POST['Cus_address']:"";
    $cn = isset($_POST['Cus_contactnum'])?$_POST['Cus_contactnum']:"";
    $ce = isset($_POST['Cus_email'])?$_POST['Cus_email']:"";

    include("config.php");

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO account (Cus_Uname, Cus_Pword) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
        // bind parameters for markers
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $cu, $cp);
        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();
        // close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client (Cus_lname, Cus_fname, Cus_address, Cus_contactnum, Cus_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        // bind parameters for markers
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $cl, $cf, $ca, $cn, $ce);
        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();
        // close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

This code assumes that your ID Column uses Auto-Increment. In this case, you do not need to include the IS in `INSERT`, it will be done automatically when the query runs.

Comment: This kind of code is very new to me. By the way I'm Just a newbie with a little knowledge so bare with me for not understanding some of your answers :)

Comment: Let me know what is not making sense or what needs more info.

Comment: it's fix now apparently my Cus_ID in account table is not AUTO INCREMENT that's why it was able to store only 1 data 

I think?

Comment: Thanks By the way for responding to my problem :)

Comment: Ok, I think... glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query for your account table.

> mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO account (Cus_ID, Cus_Uname, Cus_Pword)
>   VALUES ('null', '$cu', '$cp')");

You have placed a typo **'null'** which is a string into your Cus_ID which i assume the datatype is INT since it is a ID. Remove the single quotes **null** and see if that works.

Comment: I did try this earlier but same result too

Comment: I would just drop the ID column from the Insert query all together. This presumes that the table is set to auto-increment the ID column. If this is the case, then the ID will be populated by the next ID number when the query runs, and you do not have to enter a value in the ID column. If not, you will want to query the DB for the last ID, increment it, and enter it manually in your query.

Comment: It's fix now i just change AUTO INCREMENT my Cus_ID on my account table :) thanks for your response :)